# Accessing array offset on value of type null error in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, php-7.4

The following is my code, and it's a public function. Thie error is in PHP 7.4; I am stuck for hours, and I've tried many solutions. When I try to access the value of `$banner['img_name']`, it shows me an error on a query. I have used this syntax before; it works fine in another controller.

```php
$categories = Category::all();
$size = Category::count();

$uploaded_categories_code = NULL;

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $banner = CategoryBanner::where('category_id', $category['id'])->first();

    $imageCover = asset("images/categories/covers/" . $category['img_name']);
    $imageBanner = asset("images/categories/banners/" . $banner['img_name']);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `$banner` exists and is not null?

Comment: Hello oleg, can you provide me syntax for that?

Comment: try to `dd($banner)`;

Comment: I think you problem is work with Collection like array. Also try to `dd($category['id'])` is it exists and not null?

Comment: it exists and shows me results, so does banner when i try to echo it as just $banner, but does not execute the code when i point out an index on it

Comment: Can you update the question with screenshot with `dd($category['id']);` `dd($category);` `dd($banner);` ? I'll try to help you,

Comment: for that iteration that is erroring `$banner` is `null`

Comment: Also note that you could just do `Category::with('banner')->get();` and then access `$category->banner`. It's called eager loading, look it up. You'd still have to make sure it isn't null though.

Comment: Try `dd(Category::whereDoesntHave('banner')->count())` if count is > 0 means in at least one iteration within the foreach loop $banner will be null which causes the error.